# R strptime: yyyyww conversion using %V behaves strange

Tags: r, strptime

I was trying to create a mapping from a week key to yyyyww. For example, week-1 is 200113, week-2 is 200114, and so on.

In my system, first week starts on 2001-03-26, week starts on Monday, and weeks of the year range from 01-53.

I was doing a test with %V striptime, but found strange behavior:

```
day1 <- as.Date("20010326", "%Y%m%d")
format(day1, "%Y%V") # output "200113", which is correct
```

However, when I do it inversely:

```
as.Date("200113", format = "%Y%V") # output "2001-11-01"
as.Date("200113 1", format = "%Y%V %u") # output "2001-11-01"
```

as.Date with %Y%V failed to return me the correct date. Did I miss something?

Additional testing:

```
format(as.Date("2001-03-26")+7*39, "%Y%V") # returns "200152"
format(as.Date("2001-03-26")+7*40, "%Y%V") # returns "200101"
format(as.Date("2001-12-31"), "%Y%V") # returns "200101"
```

The last two should return "200201", it seems that R did not automatically increment the year.

Additional testing: what I'm doing now is kind of nasty but working:

```
date <- as.Date("2001-03-26") + 7*(week_key-1),
year <- year(date),
month <- month(date),
week <- as.numeric(format(date, "%V")),
yyyyww <- ifelse(week==1 & month==12, 100*(year+1)+week, 100*year+week)
```

Comment: `?strptime` says that `%V` is "(Accepted but ignored on input.)", so it will recognize the token and adjust the space for surrounding tokens, but not parse it into a date. The missing month and day are filled in by assuming "that unspecified seconds, minutes or hours are zero, and an unspecified year, month or day is the current one."

Comment: @alistaire that's helpful. No wonder it yielded 11-01, which is the date today.